# Git Add . command with Node.js not working

Tags: node.js, git, bitbucket

I am getting this error when issuing a `git add .` command

> The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
>
> warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in node_modules/babel-
>      jscs/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/plugin-manager.js.

Comment: That was because of having more node_modules in your project directory. You can add node_modules to git ignore file.So that the node_modules won't be added to git repo.

Answer (score 0):

Its not an error. its simply a warning.

You can read more about it [here](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/).

**How `autocrlf` works**:

```
core.autocrlf=true:    core.autocrlf=input:      core.autocrlf=false:

       repo                     repo                    repo
    /        \               /        \              /        \
crlf->lf    lf->crlf     crlf->lf       \          /            \      
 /              \        /                \      /                \
```

**What does this warning mean**

The warning "*LF will be replaced by CRLF*" says that you (having `autocrlf`=`true`) will lose your unix-style LF after commit-checkout cycle (it will be replaced by windows-style CRLF). Git doesn't expect you to use unix-style LF under windows.

The warning "*CRLF will be replaced by LF*" says that you (having `autocrlf`=`input`) will lose your windows-style CRLF after a commit-checkout cycle (it will be replaced by unix-style LF). Don't use `input` under windows.

**Yet another way to show how `autocrlf` works**

```
1) true:             x -> LF -> CRLF
2) input:            x -> LF -> LF
3) false:            x -> x -> x
```